# Open with chrome instead of download it

Tags: google-chrome, file-io

I encounter a problem when I try to open a txt file with chrome from my local file system(file:///home/solomon/Desktop/temp2.txt), chrome save another copy in my download folder instead of open it:(

I want to open and view any text based file with chrome, because of its convenience of highlight when finding text.So can I ask how to make this setting that use chrome to open a file instead of download it?

Comment: You'll have a better chance of an answer over at Super User

Comment: Just drag-and-drop, or open it via File > Open File...

Comment: Drag and drop makes chrome download my txt file as well:(
Do we have any setting can make it open or download certain type of file?

Comment: Recent Chrome versions appear to properly display a text file invoked via Ctrl-O.
Can you recheck?

Comment: Problem solved, It seems if special characters maybe like chinese or something else will cause behavior change to download at that version when asking the question, not sure whether still have this problem currently Jun.27 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ctrl+O`, then select that file. it allows you to view the file in the browser.

Comment: thanks Yulong, but it downloads it as well after I select it:(

Comment: @Solomon after a short search, it seems no particular solution to this other than `ctrl+O`. I actually try this using a .txt file and it works. how about change the format of that file?

Comment: change file extension not work. My chrome can open txt earlier, but cannot since an hour ago:(

BTW, I can open file:///etc/hosts-backup, but cannot open file:///home/solomon/Desktop/temp2, for temp2, chrome download it:(